# Mentioning calculated values

Tags: grammar

I have made an experiment and got many calculated values. While I was writing an article I got stuck at the sentence mentioned below. Which one is right?

> As a conclusion,
>   1. The reaction time is 5 ms.
>   2. The reaction time was 5 ms.
>   3. The reaction time was calculated to be 5 ms.

Comment: All three express the same thing and are understandable. None of them is "right" and none of them is "wrong". If you have used the past tense throughout the article to describe your experiment, use the second or third option. If you have the present tense throughout the article, the first option is best.

Comment: I was wondering about the third expression. Could it be wrongly understood like I meant to make the reaction time 5 ms, and it is not calculated.

Comment: We would need to have more context to say whether the third sentence could be misinterpreted, but it looks fine to me. In general, short and simple is best: _"As a conclusion, the reaction time is/was 5 ms."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see here 2 use case, so you may choose the right answer corresponding on your case:

1. If the result is **stable and definitive**, and therefore **will not change over time**

Then use:

> The reaction time *is* 5 ms.

2. If the result is **likely to change over time**

Then use:

> The reaction time *was* 5 ms.

or

> The reaction time *was* calculated to be 5 ms.

Which mean the reaction time **was** 5ms during this experience only but may be different if someone measure it in two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You need more context for your sentences

> 1. Our conclusion is that the expected **reaction time is 5 ms**.
> 2. Our measurement was that **the reaction time was 5 ms**.
> 3. Taking the various forms into account in our equations, **the reaction time was calculated to be 5 ms**.

All three are possible and correct, it depends on context.